# Python spacy 2.3.5 installation error within the subprocesses

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

[The error i got when installing the spacy 2.3.5 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThvtZ.png)

I ran the command pip install spacy==2.3.5

i got error for multiple lines and here is the end of the error message

Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: thinc/extra/eg.pyx
[end of output]

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.

I was trying to use pyrespaser it cannot access the config.cfg error indicating the missing of this cfg file it was due to the version of the spacy I had the 3.7.1 version but pyresparser requires the spacy 2.3.5 version which also produces errors

Answer (score 0):

You can install `spacy==2.3.5` by:

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz
```

Or

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz
```

Here is the complete link : **https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/blob/master/compatibility.json**